# Access an NSArray from Every View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, nsarray

I have a quite big `NSArray`, that i have to use in several view controllers. I get the data from a server and i don't wanna download it always when the user opens a new view.

So how can i define it as a "global variable"?

I can do it with segues, but without them it's not working. I've tried to declare an array called `dataToDestinationView` in the `DestinationViewController`, then imported it to the view where the `self.arrayToExport` is and add the lines above, but doesn't worked. Do i missed something?

```
DestinationViewController  *dataToNew = [DestinationViewController alloc]init];       
dataToNew.dataToDestinationView = self.arrayToExport;
```

***UPDATED with my try in AppDelegate:***

AppDelegate.h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) PNChannel *myChannel;
```

AppDelegate.m

```
[PubNub requestHistoryForChannel:self.myChannel from:nil to:nil limit:100 reverseHistory:NO withCompletionBlock:^(NSArray *contentArray, PNChannel *channel, PNDate *fromDate, PNDate *toDate, PNError *error) {



+ (NSArray *)mySharedArray
{
    static NSArray *sharedArray = nil;
    if (sharedArray)
        return sharedArray;

    sharedArray = contentArray;
    return sharedArray;
}


}];
```

In this case i get two errors: `Use of undeclared identifier 'self'` and  `Expected identifier or '('`. I don't understand it, because self.myChannel is declared in the .h and i'm using the same block elsewhere without the identifier problem.

SECOND UPDATE

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

 //   [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    [PubNub setDelegate:self];

    PFUser *currentChannel = [PFUser currentUser];
    self.myChannel = [PNChannel channelWithName:currentChannel.username
         shouldObservePresence:YES];

}


- (void)getMessage {

    [PubNub requestFullHistoryForChannel:self.myChannel withCompletionBlock:^(NSArray *contentArray, PNChannel *channel, PNDate *fromDate, PNDate *toDate, PNError *error) {


        + (NSArray *)mySharedArray
        {
            static NSArray *sharedArray = nil;
            if (sharedArray)
                return sharedArray;

            sharedArray = contentArray;
            return sharedArray;
        }


        NSLog(@"mokus katona %@", contactArray);

    }];
}
```

Comment: Have a look at singletons: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Singleton.html

Comment: A "global variable" is simply a variable that can be addressed from most places within your program.  For an NSArray, that means that you must somehow make the pointer to the NSArray available to each of your view controllers that need to reference it. One way to do this is to give each view controller a property that it's creator sets with the address of the array.  Another way is to place a pointer in your AppDelegate and access that pointer when needed.  Another way is to use a "singleton".  It's all a matter of somehow making the address available.

Comment: Singletons are overused and abused. As much as I see them suggested I rarely find examples where they're actually needed. Why don't you see if a static class might meet your needs? If all you need is access to date then a singleton is overkill.

Comment: @Literphor there are plenty of very good uses for singletons, but I agree this isn't one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your app delegate, declare a static variable, and a method to read it:

```
static NSArray *_message = nil;

@implementation AppDelegate

+ (NSArray *)message
{
    if (_message)
        return _message;

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [appDelegate getMessage];

    return nil;
}

- (void)getMessage {

  [PubNub requestFullHistoryForChannel:self.myChannel withCompletionBlock:^(NSArray *contentArray, PNChannel *channel, PNDate *fromDate, PNDate *toDate, PNError *error) {



      NSLog(@"mokus katona %@", contactArray);

      _message = contactArray;
  }];
}

@end
```

Comment: Can i put this into a block? Because i retrieve the data with a block method.

Comment: I could't implement the block inside the app delegate, it didn't recognized the instance variables that i declared in the `AppDelegate.h`. Is it possible to do the same in a view controller instead of the app delegate? I've tried to copy your code into my controller and alter the `MyAppDelegate` to `MyViewController`, but it's not working.

Comment: @vv88 please edit your question to include the code you tried to use that isn't working? I'll show you what you did wrong. It's definitely possible, and easy to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: @vv88 yeah that will need some changes, but can you please post more of the code? What method is this code inside for example?

Comment: I've just put this code inside the AppDelegate.m, between the _didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:_ and a custom method. But already tried another version, i've updated the question with it.

Comment: No. It doesn't crash or something, the app runs, but i can't see the log. However i get this warning `'AppDelegate *__strong' with an expression of incompatible type 'id<UIApplicationDelegate>'` on this line  ` AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];`

Comment: That warning is not causing your problem, it's harmless. Change the code it to `... = (AppDelegate *)[[ ...` and the warning will go away. I'm not sure why the log isn't running, maybe try setting a breakpoint on the `PubNub` line, or else post more of your code...

Comment: I will try it, please let me know what kind of codes should i post. My AppDelegate is quite empty.

Comment: Double check that the `getMessage` method is actually being called, and if it is then look into the PubNub class to find out why it might not execute the continuation block.

Comment: Fantastic, it seems it working. I could log it, therefore i think it will be good. I didn't called it in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, i know beginner mistake.. Can you tell me that, how can i reload the `getMessage`  method properly? The other solution retrieved the data when the app launched and stored it for the whole session. I think it's because the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method.

Comment: Just call [appDelegate getMessage] again and it will download it again.

Comment: Great, thank you very much! Just one thing, how can i call it in another view? Do i need to import something or what is the easiest way? I've tried it `self.exampleArray = message;` without any success.

Comment: `self.exampleArray = [AppDelegate message]` will read it from another view.

Comment: I get this error: `No known class method for selector 'message'` if i use this line: `self.exampleArray = [AppDelegate message]` inside my `SampleViewController.m`. I've imported the `AppDelegate.h/m` files, and also imported `SampleViewController.m` to the `AppDelegate`, but it doesn't help. Do you have any idea what could be wrong? Do i missed something?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this can help you.

In your pch file (*#project*-Prefix.pch) you can create your global variable, available from all *spaces*. Look below

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
    NSArray *myArray;
#endif
```

and in your app delegate, in your `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`, you can fill your array with the server data like this

```
[PubNub requestFullHistoryForChannel:self.myChannel withCompletionBlock:^(NSArray *contentArray, PNChannel *channel, PNDate *fromDate, PNDate *toDate, PNError *error) {
     NSLog(@"mokus katona %@", contactArray);
     myArray = contactArray;
}];
```

Now this is only one time loading and `myArray` will be available in all the controllers, models, view etc.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: It seems it's working. I've read about this topic a lot in the past days, but didn't seen a solution like this. What do you think, has it any disadvantages? When i call myArray in a random view controller (and then it's getting new data in the background), it will be updated when i reload the current view?

Comment: Now i tested it a little bit more, and the problem is that it stores the first value of the array and don't be updated when the client receive a new message. I've reloaded the view 5 times in one second and the array was the same.

Comment: Things don't happen magically. Depends how you reload it. Have you programmed before ever?

Comment: I've just reloaded the view controller where the array was used. What would you recommend to do it?

Comment: What do you mean by reloaded the view controller? Are you setting your values or images in your `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: No, i have a table view that i populate with the content from the myArray. So I'm reloading the table view.

Comment: Maybe the array is not yet loaded (Network problem). Did the Log output "mokus katona "? Any array contents?