# Updating NSArray in Singleton

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I have a block, that result contains an `NSArray` called `message`. I need to access to this array in several `UIViewControllers`. I would like to use singletons, but this array is not static, the client can receive a new message anytime, so i don't know that is it possible to update an array inside a singleton? Or reload it in every view where it was imported..

Overall, i'm not sure how could i do it. Here's the code, that shows the variable that i need to use in the other views. Any suggestions welcomed, an easier solution without singletons would be the best.

**SampleViewController.m:**

```
 PNChannel *my_channel = [PNChannel channelWithName:currentChannel.user
                             shouldObservePresence:YES];

[PubNub requestHistoryForChannel:my_channel from:nil to:nil limit:100 reverseHistory:NO    withCompletionBlock:^(NSArray *message, PNChannel *channel, PNDate *fromDate, PNDate *toDate, PNError *error) { 

//i wanna access the message array in other view controllers


}];
```

Comment: Your other question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24355605/access-an-nsarray-from-every-view-controller/24355733?noredirect=1#comment37723337_24355733) here, should be re-opened soon — as it has already had 4 votes to re-open. Please wait for that instead of posting a new question.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert sorry for this, i just wanted to ask it in a little bit different context. However thanks for dealing with my other question.

Comment: Why are you asking the same question again?  There was plenty of discussion in the other version, and if you didn't understand it that's an indication that you need to spend more time studying.

Answer (score 0):

I think singleton is a nice way for this. Other than that you can use the appdelegate property to store the value and can be called in any class as `[[[UIApplication SharedApplication] delegate] yourSharedProperty]`.In that case also you will be using the singleton but it is the appdelegate itself

Comment: You forgot to cast the delegate as `(MyAppDelegate *)` which makes the code a whole lot more ugly. I prefer to have a static method, so it's just `[MyAppDelegate mySharedProperty]`